# Could this be the subgroup test described by one axiom?

Tags: group-theory

Proposition: Let $H$ be a non-empty subset of a group $G$ w.r.t. some binary operation, $*$. We have:

$H$ is a subgroup of $G$ $\iff$ $(\forall h_1, h_2 \in H) (h_1 * h_2 ^{-1} \in H)$.

I start the first part of the proof by the supposition that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ w.r.t. the binary operation $*$. We already know that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then for all $h_1, h_2 \in H$, $h_1 * h_2 \in H$, and $h_1 \in H \implies h_1 ^{-1} \in H$ and $h_2 \in H \implies h_2 ^{-1} \in H$ so that $h_1 * h_1 ^{-1} = e \in H$ and $h_2 * h_2 ^{-1} = e \in H$, where $e$ is the unique identity element in $H$.

How could one relate this information to the fact that $(\forall h_1, h_2 \in H) (h_1 * h_2 ^{-1} \in H)$?

Kind regards.

Comment: [This is worth a look.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Subgroup_Test)

Comment: @Shaun Thank you for the information, Shaun.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By definition, a nonempty subset $H$ of $G$ forms a subgroup of $G$ iff
(1) for all $h,h'\in H$, we have $h\cdot h'\in H$, and (2) for each $h\in H$, we have $h^{-1}\in H$.

These two conditions are equivalent to the subgroup criterion: for all $h,h'\in H$, we have $h\cdot h'^{-1}\in H$.

This is easy to validate.

Comment: Perhaps your hint also is rather a criterion than a definition, since (1) and (2) imply $e\in H$ and associativity holds throughout any subset of a group.